# Can I install plugins manually on WP.com?

Tags: plugins, installation

If I have a paid blog at wordpress.com, can I install plugins manually on it?

Or must I have my own wordpress installation?

Thanks!

Comment: [tag:wordpress.com] questions are off topic per the [faq].

Comment: Silly me, apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer - no, not really. Though there are already a lot pre-installed and you can suggest new ones if you'd like. Check this article out: http://en.support.wordpress.com/plugins/